# Error SQL: ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql

Estoy empezando con `SQL` y me da un error

> SQL: ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Al crear una tabla con una `foreign key` que está correctamente escrita.
Dejo el código por si he implementado mal algo. Gracias.
El error esta en la `FK` de `TRABAJADORES`.

```
DROP TABLE CLINICAS;

DROP TABLE RECEPCIONISTAS;

--CREACIÓN DE TABLAS

CREATE TABLE CLINICAS

  (OID_CLINICA NUMBER NOT NULL,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20)NOT NULL,
  DIRECCIÓN VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (OID_CLINICA));

CREATE TABLE RECEPCIONISTAS

  (USUARIO VARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  CONTRASEÑA VARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  APELLIDOS VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  DNI CHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  EMAIL VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  TELEFONO VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TRABAJADORES

  (DNI CHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  APELLIDOS VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(DNI),
  FOREIGN KEY(OID_CLINICA) REFERENCES CLINICAS(OID_CLINICA));
```

Comment: Tienes que agregar la columna `OID_CLINICA` en la tabla trabajadores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta agregar la columna `OID_CLINICA` en la tabla TRABAJADORES

```
CREATE TABLE TRABAJADORES

  (DNI CHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  APELLIDOS VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  OID_CLINICA NUMBER NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY(DNI),
  FOREIGN KEY(OID_CLINICA) REFERENCES CLINICAS(OID_CLINICA));
```